# Misspelling a bash command takes a lot of time to respond

Tags: bash

I have a Ubuntu VPS on Contabo. I have been using quite a bit lately and one thing that keeps bothering me is that whenever I misspell a command, it takes up to a minute to tell me there was a typo. For instance, if I type ipconfig instead of ifconfig, it will take 15-20 seconds to respond with

```
Command 'ipconfig' not found, did you mean:

  command 'iwconfig' from deb wireless-tools (30~pre9-13ubuntu1)
  command 'iconfig' from deb ipmiutil (3.1.5-1)
  command 'ifconfig' from deb net-tools (1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Is there a way to make it faster? Like, make it not look for close matches to make suggestions, and just tell me that there's something wrong with the command?

Comment: Can you put `time` before the wrong command and paste the output to your original question? For example, `time ipconfigxxx`. What happens if you run the same wrong command (prepended by `time`) successively? Also paste the output of the command `free -h` to your original question.

Comment: I don't know why it would be slow - iirc it uses an sqlite database under the hood, so perhaps there's something messed up there. If you really want to disable it, it should just be a matter of unsetting the shell handle function, `unset -f command_not_found_handle`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli ```Command 'ipconfig' not found, did you mean:

  command 'iconfig' from deb ipmiutil (3.1.5-1)
  command 'iwconfig' from deb wireless-tools (30~pre9-13ubuntu1)
  command 'ifconfig' from deb net-tools (1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>


real    0m8.207s
user    0m0.108s
sys     0m0.137s```

Comment: It is always better to [edit] your question and add the requested info into your ***original*** question text formatted appropriately... Please also give info about the memory usage of your system: `free -h` and successive usage of the "wrong" command as I requested in my previous comment.